# Get number of records inserted from CREATE TABLE AS syntax

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to get the number of rows inserted into a table using the JavaScript API from a CREATE TABLE AS... DML statement, or I do need to execute another query to identify that number, such as SELECT COUNT...?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure TEST()
returns STRING
language JAVASCRIPT
as $$

    const rawSelectInto = `
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE MYTABLE1
AS
SELECT TOP 2 URI FROM MYTABLE2;
        `;

        const sql = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: rawSelectInto });

        sql.execute();

        const message = `Rows merged: ${ sql.getNumRowsAffected() }`;

        return message;
    $$;

CALL TEST();
```

I also tried getRowCount(), getColumnValue(1), and wrapping it in a transaction to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to achieve this effect for `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT`. The idea is to save queryId and use query history to access `ROWS_PRODUCED` column:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure TEST()
returns STRING
language JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
as 
$$

    const rawSelectInto = `
    CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE MYTABLE1 AS
    SELECT TOP 2 URI FROM (SELECT 1 AS URI UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3);`;

    const sql = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: rawSelectInto });

    sql.execute();

    var queryId = sql.getQueryId();
    var result = snowflake.createStatement({ 
         sqlText: `SELECT ROWS_PRODUCED 
                   FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY_BY_USER()) 
                   WHERE QUERY_ID = ?`
         ,binds: [queryId]}).execute();
     result.next();
       
    return result.getColumnValue('ROWS_PRODUCED');
$$;

CALL TEST();
-- 2
```

The stored procedure must be run as `CALLER` and not `OWNER` otherwise: "Stored procedure execution error: Requested information on the current user is not accessible in stored procedure."

Comment: Sounds like it is not possible without a separate query - in this case you are querying the query history, which can be more accurate than doing a SELECT COUNT for my case. Thanks!